# Setting up a stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm working to create a stored procedure that takes input of an id and a start and end date, then returns trips that fall within that range. I've been looking over the oracle documentation and I think I'm close, but getting a few errors yet:

```
 CREATE or replace PROCEDURE chg_per_aircraft 
  (p_aircraft_id IN RCC_AIRCRAFT.aircraft_id,
   p_start_date IN date,
   p_end_date IN date, 
   p_ttl_chg_per_acft OUT INTEGER)

AS                                             
BEGIN
  SELECT RCC_AIRCRAFT.aircraft_id, 
         SUM(RCC_CHARTER.distance * RCC_MODEL.charge_per_mile) ttl_chg
  INTO
         p_aircraft_id,
         p_ttl_chg_per_acft
FROM RCC_AIRCRAFT
full join RCC_CHARTER
on RCC_CHARTER.aircraft_id = RCC_AIRCRAFT.aircraft_id
left join RCC_MODEL
on RCC_MODEL.model_code = RCC_AIRCRAFT.model_code
Where RCC_CHARTER.trip_date > p_start_date and RCC_CHARTER.trip_date < p_end_date
group by RCC_AIRCRAFT.aircraft_id;


SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ttl_chg);
 end;
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Running this query, my errors are: 'PL/SQL: Compilation Unit Analysis Terminated' and 'PLS-00488: RCC_AIRCRAFT.Aircraft_ID must be a type'

Comment: SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ttl_chg);   will not produce any output when run as a stored procedure.  You can get output when run as pl/sql on a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first error is the parameter definition:

```
p_aircraft_id IN RCC_AIRCRAFT.aircraft_id
```

should be

```
p_aircraft_id IN RCC_AIRCRAFT.aircraft_id%TYPE
```

But then you're selecting `INTO p_aircraft_id`, which is declared as an IN parameter, so you can't set it to a new value. Is that a variable you want to pass in, or a value you want to get out? It makes more sense as something the caller supplies along with the dates, but then you'd need to use it as a filter in the select statement. If there was more than one aircraft ID - likely if it's only restricted by date - then you'd get multiple results back, which would be a too_many_rows error anyway.

Your output will only be visible to a session that is set up to handle it, so that would perhaps make more sense for the caller to do; but in any case should be:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_ttl_chg_per_acft);
```

... as `ttl_chg` only exists as a column alias, not a PL/SQL variable.

If you are passing in the aircraft ID, you might want something like this:

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE chg_per_aircraft 
  (p_aircraft_id IN RCC_AIRCRAFT.aircraft_id%TYPE,
   p_start_date IN date,
   p_end_date IN date, 
   p_ttl_chg_per_acft OUT INTEGER)
AS                                             
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(RCC_CHARTER.distance * RCC_MODEL.charge_per_mile) ttl_chg
  INTO p_ttl_chg_per_acft
  FROM RCC_AIRCRAFT
  JOIN RCC_CHARTER
  ON RCC_CHARTER.aircraft_id = RCC_AIRCRAFT.aircraft_id
  JOIN RCC_MODEL
  ON RCC_MODEL.model_code = RCC_AIRCRAFT.model_code
  WHERE RCC_CHARTER.trip_date > p_start_date
  AND RCC_CHARTER.trip_date < p_end_date
  AND RCC_AIRCRAFT.aircraft_id = p_aircraft_id
  GROUP BY RCC_AIRCRAFT.aircraft_id;

  -- just to debug!
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_ttl_chg_per_acft);
END;
/
```

I've also changed to inner joins as it doesn't seem useful to make them outer joins. This would also make more sense as a function than a procedure; though wrapping a single query in a stored program may be unnecessary anyway - though this looks like an assignment.

Comment: I would also suspect that the query might return more than 1 row in which case selecting into scalar variables would be incorrect.  My guess is that there should be a cursor involved.

Comment: Yes, though it would be OK if the aircraft ID was in fact passed in, as it would group by that single ID.

Comment: I understand what I was doing wrong with the passing of the aircraft_id parameter. Thanks for the assistance. To clarify your statement about output, must I create another pl/sql block in order to get the returned results on the console, or will 'SET SERVEROUTPUT on;' be sufficient?

Comment: @Mitch - if you're running this in SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer then you can set serveroutput on, and you'll see the output when you run it (which will be from an anonymous block anyway, so you could do the output from that - see what it gets back). But you shouldn't assume someone else calling your procedure will see the output. It's OK for debugging in a client environment you control.